# Layer responsive images on top of each other with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get two images on top of each other, while also being centered both vertically and horizontally on screen. If I make them both positioned relatively, the first one is centered great, while the second one appears beneath the first.

```
#copy, #logo {
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto; 
}
```

So I added a wrapper and positioned that relatively and positioned the images absolutely. Now they stack on one another, but I lost my centering.

```
#wrapper {
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: tranlasteY(-50%);
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

#copy, #logo {
position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Here's a code pen with my exact code http://codepen.io/kathryncrawford/pen/vNwNdL

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7gkwxs6c/1/embedded/result//

Comment: Works great! Make that an answer and I'll mark it if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can omit the wrapper and just use absolute positioning on the children elements, setting the margin to auto and the top/right/bottom/left to 0:

```css
#copy, #logo {
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    margin:auto;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <img id="copy" class="img-responsive" src="http://fillmurray.com/600/600"></img>
    <img id="logo" class="img-responsive" src="http://fillmurray.com/500/500"></img>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You got to make `html`, `body`, the `#wrapper` and all the parent elements for the images to occupy all the screen, with `height:100%`. Set the positioning of the images absolute based on `#wrapper` with position:relative on it. And voilá, set the XY positioning margin to 50% (as you did) and translate(-50%) (as you did).

```
body,html{
  padding:0;
  height:100%;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height:100%;
}

#copy, #logo {
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}
```

[Pen](http://codepen.io/teefars/pen/PPvPym)

Obs: Great images btw

Comment: Thanks! Yeah Fill Murray is my favorite. Placecage is a close second, because who can say no to Nic Cage gifs as placeholders?

Comment: Tried this. Sadly, all my stuff ended up on the right side of the screen and not centered anymore :(

Comment: Try `width:100%` also for the wrapper;

Comment: Oh, I missed the translateX part. That might help :P